# SWT - Transparent Radio Button inside Table

Tags: java, swt

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make an SWT radio button cell use the current underlying mechanism for determining 'alternating row' colors and 'selected row' colors in a table.

The table (by default?) already has the alternating/selected row colors working and all other columns/rows correctly display them. Note - I've been digging around through the code but can't figure out how the alternate/selected row colors are getting set. One would assume it's the ColumnLabelProvider, but it's not. I see an example of how to manually set the alternating colors in the link below, but I want to avoid doing that because I wouldn't be using whatever architecture is already being used under the hood.

- http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet041TableViewerAlternatingColors.java

A code sample is provided below.  Any help would be appreciated!!

```
private Map<Object, Button> buttons = new HashMap<>();
...

private void createColumns(final TableViewer viewer) {
    final TableViewerColumn column0 = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.CENTER);
    column0.getColumn().setWidth(50);
    column0.getColumn().setText("MyColumnTitle");
    column0.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

        @Override
        public void update(final ViewerCell cell) {
            cell.setImage(null);
            cell.setText(null);

            Button button;
            if (buttons.containsKey(cell.getElement())) {
                button = buttons.get(cell.getElement());
            } else {
                final TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
                button = new Button((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(), SWT.RADIO);
                buttons.put(cell.getElement(), button);

                // Make the radio button clickable
                final TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
                editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
                editor.grabHorizontal = true;
                editor.minimumWidth = 50;                    
                editor.setEditor(button, item, cell.getColumnIndex());
                editor.layout();
            }

// Some things I have tried without success                
// button.setBackground(null);
// button.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND));
// cell.getViewerRow().getControl().getParent().setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_NONE);
// cell.setBackground(cell.getNeighbor(ViewerCell.RIGHT, true).getBackground());
// cell.setForeground(cell.getNeighbor(ViewerCell.RIGHT, true).getForeground());
        }
    });

    // This is a column that works fine (shows alternating rows/highlighting as expected)
    final TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEFT);
    column.getColumn().setWidth(240);
    column.getColumn().setText("ColumnName");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(final Object element) {
            if (element instanceof MyObject) {
                return MyObject.getText();
            }
            return super.getText(element);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'd first would dump JFace and start with pure SWT. This will help you to better understand how things belong together.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not feasible since this is a part of a larger project that uses JFace

Comment: But you could try out with pure SWT first and if you found a solution there, adopt it to JFace. What operating system you are running?

Answer (score 1):

If the alternating row colors are provided by the platform, you can ^set the background mode of the table to `SWT.INHERIT_FORCE`

```
table.setBackgroundMode( SWT.INHERIT_FORCE );
```

If the row colors are set through a label provider, you need to set the background color of the button to match the row on which the button is placed.

Here is a plain SWT snippet that I does what I think you are looking for. Every even row has a green background and the radio button is assigned the background of the selected item before it is activated.

```
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell( display );
    shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
    Table table = new Table( shell, SWT.NONE );
    TableColumn column = new TableColumn( table, 0 );
    column.setWidth( 100 );
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      TableItem item = new TableItem( table, SWT.NONE );
      item.setText( "item " + i );
      if( i % 2 == 0 ) {
        item.setBackground( display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_GREEN ) );
      }
    }
    final Button button = new Button( table, SWT.RADIO );
    button.setText( "radio" );
    table.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
      public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent event ) {
        TableItem item = ( TableItem )event.item;
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor( item.getParent() );
        button.setText( item.getText() );
        button.setBackground( item.getBackground() );
        editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor( button, item, 0 );
        editor.layout();
      }
    } );
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
      if( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is responsible for the alternating row colors? Or clarify where they come from (which window system are you running on)?

Comment: I'm running in a linux OS. I have no clue where the code is that is responsible for alternating row colors (As per my original post, I'm guessing it's supposed to be part of the ColumnLabelProvider but I don't see it in there).

Comment: The `ColumnLabelProvider`does not change brackground colors on its own. Have you tried other operating systems? What does the code that I posted look like?